# Links do not receive the focus when clicked on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

I came across a very strange behaviour on Chrome which seems like a bug to me: when you click a link, the link does not receive the focus. Worse, the body takes the focus instead.

This behaviour can be observed here: http://jsfiddle.net/YfbR7/4/ (`see code sample here`)

Is this a bug? Is this standard behaviour? Is there any workaround to make the links receive the focus on mouse down, like on the other browsers?

Comment: The same behaviour also applies to checkboxes, see question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400190/checkboxes-do-not-receive-the-focus-when-clicked-on-chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add tab index to anchor tag it should work, it's not a bug its a web kit thingy.

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Wow I was not expecting that one! It's working great. I am having the same issues with checkboxes, but I will open a new question for that one as you have answered the original question.

Comment: And here is the explanation why this helps: "By giving it a tabindex you can make any element you like focusable. The focus and blur events should work on such elements." Works in all browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Comment: Beware that using tabindex values greater than 0 can cause accessibility issues.

MDN has a good article on `tabindex` which has this warning:
"Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0. Doing so makes it difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and operate page content."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 3):

A link should always natively receive focus. If your link does not have a `href` attribute it won't (not sure the use case of a link without a href though!).

Comment: This is the best answer here, tbh

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer:

Since setting `tabindex` to `1` would change the <kbd>TAB</kbd> behavior, I recommend setting it to `-1` instead: it won't break the <kbd>TAB</kbd> navigation and will still enable it from being focused.

```
<a href="#" tabindex="-1">Example</a>
```

By the way, [here's a very nice article](http://www.sitepoint.com/when-do-elements-take-the-focus/) regarding these concerns.

---

<sub>Note: the same thing happened with me, but just on Safari: probably Chrome has already that issue fixed.</sub>