# Anchor elements do not receive focus when clicked

Tags: html

I have noticed on webkit browsers that anchor elements `<a href=""></a>` do not receive focus when clicked.  Inputs and divs (with tabindex set) do.  Of course, tabbing will set focus to an anchor, as will javascript `.focus()`.

My questions:  Why does this happen?  and does anyone know any tricks to make an anchor receive focus upon click?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Links do not receive the focus when clicked on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399750/links-do-not-receive-the-focus-when-clicked-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add tabindex to anchor tag.

Following link will help: [tabindex usage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)